# "Charges", "chargements" et "sollicitations mécaniques"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes, physique

J'ai lu dans des livres

> des charges mécaniques, des chargements mécaniques, des sollicitations mécaniques.

Dans ce contexte (mécanique) ces expressions peuvent-elles être employées de façon interchangeable ?

Laquelle traduit le mieux en français « [mechanical load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_load) » ?

Comment: Tu as lié _mechanical loading_ à l'article intitulé _mechanical load_... je n'y connais rien mais voir aussi [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=MECHANICAL+LOAD&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour traduire *load* au sens mécanique, la *charge* est le mot de sens le plus proche et s'emploie dans des contextes similaires.

Le mot *mechanical loading* est parfois utilisé en anglais avec le même sens, mais en français, dans ce domaine, je préférerais *charge* à *chargement*, qui a plutôt tendance à représenter le contenu d'un véhicule.

La *sollicitation mécanique* est très proche. Je perçois deux nuances :

- *Charge* d'une part implique une certaine quantité définie de force ou de moment appliqué à un matériau, alors que la sollicitation n'est pas forcément une quantité définie ;
- *Charge* a parfois une connotation d'utilité, qui permet des expressions telles que *charge de neige* pour indiquer *la charge causée par le poids de la neige sur un toit*, alors que *sollicitation* n'a pas forcément cette connotation d'utilité et décrit plus purement un état physique.

Answer (score 4):

Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française définit une [charge](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/charge) et un [chargement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chargement) comme « ce qui pèse sur quelqu'un ou quelque chose », tandis qu'une [sollicitation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sollicitation) est « l'action d'exercer une action physique sur un corps, une pièce de mécanisme ou un appareil ; le résultat de cette action ».

Ainsi, pour un effort créé **du fait de la pesanteur** par un objet externe, ces trois termes peuvent être utilisés sans distinction : *la charge/le chargement/la sollicitation mécanique due à la couverture sur la charpente*. Mais pour **tous les autres efforts** envisageables, seuls le mot « sollicitation » semble correct : *les sollicitations mécaniques dues à la pression du gaz sur le canon*.

Comment: Je ne crois pas que ce soit correct. Par exemple le terme "charge de vent" est courant et n'a pas trait à la pesanteur.

Answer (score 1):

'Load' est un état ou une quantité, alors que 'loading' est une action. Donc 'solliciter mécaniquement' (en adaptant la phrase) est plus exact que 'sollicitations mécaniques' par exemple.

PS : 'load' est un peu familier (par rapport à 'stress' ou 'pressure').

Comment: "Load" est un verbe désignant une action, "loading" un nom désignant le résultat de cette action. Je vois mal comment ta réponse peut être correcte…

Comment: @Blackhole Suivant le contexte, *load* et *loading* peuvent tout deux être utilisés comme des noms commun ou des verbes. (The load ou the loading= la charge, le chargement), (Loading=chargeant)